# 'ls' and file managers hang on home directory after installing KDE

Tags: kde, home-directory, ls

Today I installed KDE on my Ubuntu 12.04 using:

```
apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Everything is running fine, apart from one very strange issue: it seems impossible to list the files in my home directory, in any file manager or by using the 'ls' command.

For example:

```
ls ~/
```

just hangs, whereas

```
ls ~/Dropbox
```

works fine.

Any help will be appreciated?

EDIT: "sudo ls" works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply restarting my computer solved the problem.  I'm still not sure why this happened in the first place though.

Comment: you should mark this as solved. :)

Comment: Yeah, upto you. But there'd be one less unsolved question, then.